# Streamline results in mapPartitions (Spark)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Is there a way to return partial results in `mapPartitions()` ?

Currently I use it like this:

```
myRDD.mapPartitions{
  iter: iterator[InputType] => {
    val additionalData = <some costly init operation>
    val results = ArrayBuffer[OutputType]()
    for(input: InputType <- iter) results += (transform(input, additionalData))
    results.iterator
  }
}
```

But of course if a partition is too big the `results` array will throw an OOM exception.

So my question: is there a way to send partial results every once in a while so as to avoid any OOM ?

I want to stick to `mapPartitions` because I initialize a costly object (e.g. get the value of a big broadcasted variable) before processing the input and I don't want to do that at every record like with `map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `additionalData` doesn't access the iterator you can just `map`:

```
myRDD.mapPartitions{
  iter: iterator[InputType] => {
    val additionalData = ???
    iter.map(input => transform(input, additionalData))
}}
```